# NodeQuery security?

Tags: monitoring

I recently used NodeQuery and found it very useful. But it has not been updated since 2014 and since there is no activity in the github repo I am not clear about the project's status.

Anybody here knows about this project and where it is going? I want to know if NodeQuery is still safe to use because it installs something on the server.

Comment: @Sven I changed question from asking about alternative to security, can you open it again?

Comment: No, because we are not the project and can't answer that. Please read our [help].

Comment: The question doesn't requests for a product any more, thus it can be reopened.

Comment: I suggest to fork the project and insert your local modifications in it. If there is, at least, a minimal change in the project regularly, it is enough to revitalize it. Btw, thanks for the tip - I found nagios always a little bit as if it had been started in the seventies. I suggest to reask your question on http://opensource.stackexchange.com .